# How to get the count of columns which are having NA in r?

Tags: r, count, null, na

I have a dataset where the columns are more than 1000. Now I know that there are many columns which are having all the entries as NA. I want to know the count of columns which are having NA. For example,
If there are 100 columns with NA values I want the output to be 100. I have researched many sites to find the answer but nothing helped. This is what I tried.

```
colnames(data)[colSums(is.na(data)) > 0]
```

But this is returning me all the columns. But I want only the count.

Comment: `sum(sapply(data, function(col) any(is.na(col)))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is base you could run

```
sum(sapply(data, function(col) any(is.na(col)))
```

(which would work for e.g. data.frames). `sapply` returns a vector of boolean values e.g. `[1] True False True` for a three-column data.frame with two columns with any missing values in it. The boolean values translates to 1's that can be summed.

---

If `data` is a matrix, substitute `sapply` for apply and do

```
sum(apply(as.matrix(a), 2, function(col) any(is.na(col))))
```

---

*EDIT* After reading the OP's question once again, i realised the OP wants the columns where the columns contain ALL NA's. This can be obtained by substituting `any` for `all`, i.e.

```
sum(sapply(data, function(col) all(is.na(col))))
```

Comment: This was helpful to check if there are nulls in all the columns

Comment: @Jeslin Lois I read this: "I want to know the count of columns which are having NA" for my first answer. See the updated ans for how to check columns which have all NA's.

Comment: @itswlg it works! I have around 1082 columns in total out of which 588 contains only NAs. It is correctly filtered by the latest code which you have provided.

Comment: @JeslinLois Great! If you feel like this answered your question, please accept the answer by clicking on the check mark to the left!

Answer (score 1):

Try :

```
sum(colSums(is.na(data)) == nrow(data))
#[1] 2
```

Or the opposite

```
sum(colSums(!is.na(data)) == 0)
```

---

You can also use `Filter`

```
length(Filter(function(x) all(is.na(x)), data))
```

Or with `dplyr` :

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% select_if(~all(is.na(.))) %>% ncol
```

**data**

```
data <- data.frame(a = c(1, 2, NA, 4), b = NA, c = letters[1:4], d = NA)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use this i guess :

```
library(DataExplorer)
plot_missing(iris) #this will print all the missing values in the plot 
profile_missing(iris) #this will print all the missing values columns with numbers like this
```

[Output Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aciD7.png)

once you got them in data frame keep columns > 0 you will get list of columns which have `NA`.

Answer (score 1):

To get the number of columns containing `NA` you can use `colSums` and `sum`:

```
sum(colSums(is.na(data)) > 0)
```

To get the number of columns containing only `NA` I would use the solution from @ronak-shah (`sum(colSums(!is.na(data)) == 0)`)